# How can I integrate elasticsearch to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, kibana

I was working on a project which is required to use elasticsearch. I followed the guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html
It works perfectly for me:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$hosts = [
    'myhost'
];
$client = ClientBuilder::create()           // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
                    ->setHosts($hosts)      // Set the hosts
                    ->build();  
$params = [
    'index' => 'php-demo-index',

    'type' => 'doc',
    'id'    => 'my_id',
    'body'  => ['testField' => 'abc']
];

$response = $client->index($params);
print_r($response);
```

Now, that's only a basic thing. Now, what I want is to integrate this with Mysql i.e. as I update or insert into my table in database, it get indexed automatically in elasticsearch.
I know, we have Logstash that can query db constantly after a given interval and index into elasticsearch. But, I want indexing to be happened automatically after insertion into db using PHP without logstash.
I know such a library in (nodeJs+mongodb) ie. mongoosastics: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic. Is there any library available in php which can do such a task automatically. Please provide me the sample code, if you know one.

Comment: Why not just add your record to elasticsearch after/while you insert it into your mysql database?

Comment: @Cully, thankyou for commenting. Yes, we can do that, but I'm searching for library like mongoosastics in php, which acts as as a plugin for i.e. it effects elasticsearch automatically after a database operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed libraries to automate this task. However it generally requires the use of an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Doctrine in order gracefully hook in to your database implementation. If you are able to use the [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) framework in your project there is a library called [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle) which keeps your indices in sync with your database operations.